# c++11. Is it possible to do this: string foo = cout << (.00000023)*(.00000023) << endl; -with precision

Tags: c++, string, c++11, variable-assignment

I want to save the output from

```
  std::cout << endl << std::setprecision(20) << std::fixed;
  cout << ((.0000023)*(.00000023))<< endl;
```

Which is: `0.00000000000052900000`

-into a string variable.

Comment: Google `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 3):

You could split this into steps using `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream output;
output << << endl << std::setprecision(20) << std::fixed;
output << ((.0000023)*(.00000023))<< endl;
std::string result_string = output.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try std::ostringstream:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << ...;
std::string result(oss.str());
```

Note that it's slow on some platfroms/compilers.

Answer (score 0):

See [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to stream into a string.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << 10 + 10;
    std::string result = stream.str(); // result contains "20"
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: String manipulators work with `std::ostringstream` just like `std::cout`.

```
stream << std::fixed << (1.0 / 100.0); // result will contain "0.010000"
```

Comment: You forgot to set the precision.

Comment: This is an example, notice that I did not do any of the math from the original question. The actual math is irrelevant to the question, which is to convert a result to a string. I'll add a note that stream manipulators work for `std::ostringstream` just like `std::cout`.